# How can I display the created cube in Revit API?

Tags: c#, class-library, revit-api

This might sound like a very basic question, and I apologize for that - however, I literally couldn't find anything about this anywhere around.

I am trying to make a command which creates a cube made of model lines and puts it in the drawing. For the cube creation, I've found on Jeremy Tammik's blog some documentation about this and got the following code:

```
static Solid CreateCube(double d)
{
     return CreateRectangularPrism(
          XYZ.Zero, d, d, d);
}
static Solid CreateRectangularPrism(
     XYZ center,
     double d1,
     double d2,
     double d3)
{
     List<Curve> profile = new List<Curve>();
     XYZ profile00 = new XYZ(-d1 / 2, -d2 / 2, -d3 / 2);
     XYZ profile01 = new XYZ(-d1 / 2, d2 / 2, -d3 / 2);
     XYZ profile11 = new XYZ(d1 / 2, d2 / 2, -d3 / 2);
     XYZ profile10 = new XYZ(d1 / 2, -d2 / 2, -d3 / 2);

     profile.Add(Line.CreateBound(profile00, profile01));
     profile.Add(Line.CreateBound(profile01, profile11));
     profile.Add(Line.CreateBound(profile11, profile10));
     profile.Add(Line.CreateBound(profile10, profile00));

     CurveLoop curveLoop = CurveLoop.Create(profile);

     SolidOptions options = new SolidOptions(
     ElementId.InvalidElementId,
     ElementId.InvalidElementId);

     return GeometryCreationUtilities
     .CreateExtrusionGeometry(
     new CurveLoop[] { curveLoop },
     XYZ.BasisZ, d3, options);
}
```

In the Execute() method, I only have this:

```
     using (Transaction tx = new Transaction(doc))
     {
        tx.Start("create cube");


        Solid cube = CreateCube(100);
        
        // What shall I do next??
        tx.Commit();
     }
```

At this point I am stuck, as I can't seem to find any way to display this cube in the drawing. Moreover, what is further confusing me is that the cube's Id is set to -1. I also checked its visibility in code and it seems to hold true, however, it does not appear anywhere in the drawing. What am I missing out? How can I make it appear in the drawing?

Any tips, documentation is code is highly welcome!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a GeometryObject but no Revit Element, then you cannot see any object because there is no a database object to show.

You could create a DirectShape and set the geometry that you created :

```
     var ds = DirectShape.CreateElement(revitDocument, new ElementId(BuiltInCategory.OST_GenericModel));
     ds.SetName("Cube");
     ds.SetShape(new List<GeometryObject>() { cube });
```